# How to increase height of Rectangle according to text in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am not able to increase height of Rectangle (or RowLayout) wrapped around Text item that could dynamically change (chat message for example).

I tried bunch of approaches (Text.paintedHeight, childrenRect ...) but everything looks funky when text is wrapped.

My goal is display chat messages, stretch them according their wrapped text height.

Thanks for any input.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true

width: 900
height: 500

ColumnLayout {
    width: parent.width
    spacing: 2

    RowLayout {
        id: rowLayout
        spacing: 3

        Rectangle {
            height: 50
            width: 50
            color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle
            width: 50
            color: "green"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            Text {
                id: element
                text: "If the GridLayout is resized, all items in the layout will be rearranged. It is similar to the widget-based QGridLayout. All visible children of the GridLayout element will belong to the layout. If you want a layout with just one row or one column, you can use the RowLayout or ColumnLayout. These offer a bit more convenient API, and improve readability.\n\nBy default items will be arranged according to the flow property. The default value of the flow property is GridLayout.LeftToRight.\n\nIf the columns property is specified, it will be treated as a maximum limit of how many columns the layout can have, before the auto-positioning wraps back to the beginning of the next row. The columns property is only used when flow is GridLayout.LeftToRight."
                anchors.rightMargin: 10
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                anchors.fill: parent
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                clip: false
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want the Rectangle to resize to the text? I see you have `width: 50`, what if the text is a single letter (or emoji)? Do you want the Rectangle to still be 50 wide or do you want it to be smaller and 50 is more a max width after which the text should wrap ?

Comment: That 'width: 50' is typo, three lines below its overwritten by Layout.fillWidth: true, so its ignored. The goal is to have rectangle filling whole row, that first rectangle denotes icon. I am interested in growing height, when too long text is included, width is taken care of by that fillWidth, but rectangle wasn't growing its height when longer text was present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the `implicitHeight` and `implicitWidth` for `Rectangle` (and `Item` for that matter).

```
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        width: 50
        color: "green"
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        implicitWidth: element.implicitWidth
        implicitHeight: element.implicitHeight

        Text {
            id: element
            anchors.fill: parent
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            clip: false
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }
    }
```

Please note that your current setup with `anchors.margins` is slightly conflicting here, since that is not counted in the `implicitHeight`/`Width`, so I left them out.

---

***Another option*** would be to set the `background` for a `Label` (from `QtQuick.Controls`) to your desired `Rectangle`, that will then be stretched properly:

```
 Label {
      leftPadding: 10
      rightPadding: 10
      ...

      background: Rectangle {
          color: "green"
      }
 }
```

In my opinion this would give you easier control about the position of your text.

Comment: I managed to succeed with first approach, will try second one probably too. Is this recommended way, seems like a lot of work to achieve what one would say simple task.. But thanks nevertheless

Comment: In the second approach you don't have to mess with adding padding here and there, which I find less work. Also, you can put the complete design of one label+background/rectangle in it's own qml file, making it very portable